# SQL Server take a time duration and parse the time into the hour parts of that duration

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, temporal

I am posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323718/sql-server-and-allocate-time-into-hour-parts) again because the project has changed and the previous answers don't return the desired results. Ambulances and fire trucks have the dispatch time when an emergency occurred and an end time for when the emergency was declared over.

Event 1 starts on May 1, 2021 10:17:33 and ends at may 1, 2021 10:33:41.

Event 2 starts on May 1, 2021 11:50:52 and ends at May 1, 2021 13:18:21.

I would like to parse the amount of time from the start to the end and place it into the hour parts when it occurs. For example; Event 1 starts at 10:17 and ends at 10:33. It would place 16 minutes minutes in the 10:00 hour part for that day. Event 2 would place 10 minutes in the 11:00 hour part, 60 minutes in the 12:00 hour part and 18 minutes in the 13:00 hour part. Place the minutes in the hours during which the event occured.

The results should look the following. Although I am flexible. For example, if the name of the truck cannot be returned in the results that would be ok because if the EventID is there, I could relate back to the original table.

| EventID | Ambulance | EventDayOfYear | EventHour | MinutesAllocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Medic10 | 121 | 10 | 16 |
| 1 | Medic10 | 121 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | Ladder73 | 121 | 11 | 10 |
| 2 | Ladder73 | 121 | 12 | 60 |
| 2 | Ladder73 | 121 | 13 | 18 |
| 3 | Engine41 | 121 | 13 | 33 |
| 3 | Engine41 | 121 | 14 | 21 |
| 4 | Medic83 | 121 | 15 | 32 |
| 4 | Medic83 | 121 | 16 | 5 |
| 5 | Rescue32 | 121 | 16 | 33 |
| 6 | Medic09 | 121 | 23 | 16 |
| 6 | Medic09 | 122 | 0 | 39 |
| 7 | Engine18 | 121 | 23 | 28 |
| 7 | Engine18 | 122 | 0 | 60 |
| 7 | Engine18 | 122 | 1 | 34 |
| 8 | Rescue63 | 122 | 0 | 35 |

The following SQL code comes close to working to deliver the right result. **But it does not overlap days**. There are many emergency events that start at 2300 hours and last until 0300 hours the following day.

```
DECLARE @tempFireEvents TABLE
(
  EventID INT NOT NULL
, Apparatus VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, StartDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
, EndDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
, DurationInSeconds INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @tempFireEvents
VALUES
  (1, 'Medic10', 'may 1, 2021 10:17:33', 'may 1, 2021 10:33:41', 968) /*This event is entirely within 1000 hours*/
, (2, 'Ladder73', 'may 1, 2021 11:50:52', 'may 1, 2021 13:18:21', 5249) /*This event spans 1100, 1200 and 1300 hours*/
, (3, 'Engine41', 'may 1, 2021 13:27:17', 'may 1, 2021 14:21:18', 3241) /*This event overlaps 1300 and 1400 hours*/
, (4, 'Medic83', 'may 1, 2021 15:28:08', 'may 1, 2021 16:05:48', 2260) /*This event overlaps 1500 and 1600 hours*/
, (5, 'Rescue32', 'may 1, 2021 16:20:43', 'may 1, 2021 16:53:28', 1965) /*This event is entirely within the 1600 hour part*/
, (6, 'Medic09', 'may 1, 2021 23:44:06', 'may 2, 2021 00:39:52', 3346) /*Notice this overlaps the 2300 and 0000 hours into the following day*/
, (7, 'Engine18', 'may 1, 2021 23:32:58', 'may 2, 2021 01:34:13', 7275) /*Notice this overlaps the 2300, 0000 and 0100 hours into the following day*/
, (8, 'Rescue63', 'may 2, 2021 00:17:45', 'may 2, 2021 00:52:09', 2064) /*Notice this is the 00 hour of the day and does not show in the results*/
;

WITH AllHours AS
(
SELECT 1 AS hourInt
UNION ALL
SELECT hourInt + 1
FROM AllHours
WHERE hourInt < 23
)
,
Combined AS
(
SELECT 
  T.EventID
, H.hourInt
, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, T.StartDateTime) = H.hourInt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isStart
, CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, T.EndDateTime) = H.hourInt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isEnd
, T.StartDateTime
, T.EndDateTime
FROM @tempFireEvents AS [T]
JOIN AllHours AS [H] ON H.hourInt BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, T.StartDateTime) AND DATEPART(HOUR,T.EndDateTime)
)

SELECT 
  EventID
, hourInt
, CASE WHEN isStart = 1 AND isEnd = 0 THEN 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDateTime)
  WHEN isStart = 0 AND isEnd = 1 THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, EndDateTime)
  WHEN isStart = 1 AND isEnd = 1 THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, EndDateTime) -  DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDateTime)
  ELSE 60
  END AS MinutesInThisHour
FROM Combined
ORDER BY EventID ASC, hourint ASC
;
```

I have a suspiction that SQL Server may not be the best method to achieve the goal. It may need to be written in Python with increment and decrement and counters.

If it helps, I have a calendar table that looks like:

```
May 1, 2021 00:00:00
May 1, 2021 01:00:00
May 1, 2021 02:00:00
May 1, 2021 03:00:00
May 1, 2021 04:00:00
May 1, 2021 05:00:00
May 1, 2021 06:00:00
```

Would a calendar table be useful in solving this problem?

Comment: Please don't use HTML for your questions. Things like the `<body>` tag break the markdown.

Comment: Your closing statement *"I have a calendar table that looks like:"* implies that your calendar table is storing dates as a `varchar`. If so, then that calendar table is going to be far from useful I am afraid. There are date and time data types for a reason.

Comment: When I wrote the question Stack Overflow had an error message: It would not post without a body tag. When I put in the <body> tag the error message went away. Secondly, The date time values are stored in SQL Server as DATETIME.

Comment: Shouldn't AllHours being returning 0..23? Also, why a recursive CTE? Why not `with AllHours as (select * from (values (0), (1), ... , (23)) H(HourInt) )` or even a Tally Table?

Comment: AlwaysLearning: your proposed solution does not solve the problem of events 6 and 7 which overlap days. Event 6 starts at the 2300 hour and ends in the 00:00 hour. Event 7 starts at 2300, goes all the way through the 00:00 hour and ends in the 01:00 hour. the problem I am trying to solve is how to write code that deals with events that overlap days. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
CREATE TABLE tempFireEvents
(
EventID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
StartDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
EndDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO tempFireEvents
VALUES
('fire0001', 'november 1, 2018 10:45:00', 'november 2, 2018 11:30:00'),
('fire0002', 'november 1, 2018 11:50:00', 'november 1, 2018 13:10:00'),
('fire0003', 'november 1, 2018 13:20:00', 'november 1, 2018 14:20:00'),
('fire0004', 'november 1, 2018 15:25:00', 'november 1, 2018 16:05:00'),
('fire0005', 'november 1, 2018 16:20:00', 'november 2, 2018 17:00:00'),
('fire0006', 'november 1, 2018 16:20:00', 'november 1, 2018 17:01:00');

select e.*, hr.ld, 
   60 - case when e.startdatetime > hr.ld then datepart(minute, e.startdatetime) else 0 end
   + case when e.enddatetime < hr.ud then datepart(minute, e.enddatetime)-60 else 0 end as allocatedminutes
from tempFireEvents as e
cross apply
(
  select
    dateadd(hour, datepart(hour,e.startdatetime)+t.rn-1, cast(cast(e.startdatetime as date) as datetime)) as ld, 
    dateadd(hour, datepart(hour,e.startdatetime)+t.rn, cast(cast(e.startdatetime as date) as datetime)) as ud,
    rn
  from
  (
    -- a tally, max 100 rows .. max 100 hours duration
    select top (1+datediff(hour,e.startdatetime,dateadd(minute, -1, e.enddatetime))) row_number() over(order by @@spid) as rn
    from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as a(n)
    cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as b(n)
  ) as t
) as hr;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thoughtful post.  The SQL code you posted answers my question and puts the minutes of activity in bins of the hours of each day. It also handles the events that overlap dates on the calendar. However, there is one issue which prevents this code from being used. There is a line of code: FROM (VALUES(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), etc. This limits the number of observations which can be returned. I have about 9000 events to be processed. How can I adapt this code to scale upward?

Comment: ..@DavidFortMyers, the `FROM (VALUES..)` part is "executed"/APPLYied per event/for each event row.  The max 100 rows restriction applies to the duration (StartDatetime-EndDatetime) of an event: If an event is longer than 100 hours, the code will return the first 100 "hour bins" and it will "miss" the rest of the duration...If events cannot be longer than 100 hours, then it will work fine, for any number of events. You could extend the code (up to 1000 hours per event etc) or use a tally function or a tally table which will work for any maximum duration/hours...

Comment: ...@DavidFortMyers ... and if you feel like optimizing further: the code ,as-is, performs calculations&comparisons for each hour bin: `60 - case + case` ... however if an event covers more than two hours...then the comparisons/arithmetics are actually needed only for the first hour (rn=1) and the last hour(rn=datediff(Start - [End-1minute]). All other in-between hours will default to 60 minutes.. Example, event starts at 13:XX and ends at 18:YY: rn.1 = 60-XX mins | rn.6=YY mins, rn.2&rn.3&rn.4&rn.4 = 60 mins(those do not require actual calculations..)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Your professional assistance has made this project much easier. I modified your code to work with our SQL Server and it is working perfectly. Prior to this, I had 300 lines of SQL code with about twenty CASE statements. It was difficult to understand and prone to errors. Your code greatly simplifies everything. Further, using your SQL query returns data that is easier to analyze statistically. I can look at the sum number of hours for each hour and for each day of the week. This output can be analyzed statistically, and with visualizations. Thank you for helping me